# how to import array in react component (array with images names, that reads from folder)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, import

here I read all images in folder and create an array with the names of the images. Then I want to send an array to my react component to show it in my select

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


const PictureObjectCreator = (pathTo) =>  {
  let arrayOut = []
  let allFiles = fs.readdirSync(pathTo)


  for (let i = 0 ; i < allFiles.length ; i+=1){
    allFiles[i] = path.basename(allFiles[i] , '.webp');
    allFiles[i] = allFiles[i].split('_').join(' ')
    arrayOut[i] = {name: allFiles[i] , value: allFiles[i]}
  }

  return arrayOut
}


let gameMode3Path = '../../images/imageForGameMode3'

const gameMode1Select = PictureObjectCreator(gameMode1Path);
const LCEGOList = PictureObjectCreator(gameMode3Path);

exports.LCEGOList = LCEGOList
```

here I was able to output my array

```
const List = require('./LCDirectoryFileNameReader')
const LCEGOList = List.LCEGOList

console.log(LCEGOList);
```

but when I tried to import the array in my react component this error shows up

Uncaught TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function

Please give me advise how to deal with it, I would be very grateful.

I tried to import in React like this

```
const List = require('./LCDirectoryFileNameReader')
const LCEGOList = List.LCEGOList
```

and this

`import { LCEGOList } from "../../LCDitectoryFileNameReader/test";`

but in both cases, I received an error